# How to get the date of the most recent image in a EarthEngine collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I have a daily pipeline running to retreive data on GEE. it  is only triggered when new data have been updated on GEE.

I have the current list of image collection:

```py
list_collection = [
        "NASA/SMAP/SPL4SMGP/007",
        "MODIS/061/MOD15A2H",
        "MODIS/061/MOD13Q1",
        "JAXA/GPM_L3/GSMaP/v6/operational",
        "ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY",
        "MODIS/061/MOD09A1",
        "ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/DAILY_AGGR",
        "MODIS/061/MOD09Q1",
    ]
```

And for each one I would like to get the most recent image date.

My current implementation is sorting the image collections which is super slow.

```py
def get_latest_date(collection):
    ic = ee.imagecollection(collection)
    image = ic.sort("system:time_start", False).first()
    return ee.Date(image.get("system:time_start")).format("YYYY-MM-dd").getInfo()
```

Is there a faster way to proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

the [`geetools`](https://geetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) extension has a [`getSTAC`](https://geetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autoapi/geetools/ImageCollection/index.html#geetools.ImageCollection.ImageCollectionAccessor.getSTAC) method that can get all the information we need without spending a single EECU.

from the STAC representation of my collection I can ge the temporal extent of the dataset thus the latest updated image:

```py
import ee, geetools

list_collection = [
        "NASA/SMAP/SPL4SMGP/007",
        "MODIS/061/MOD15A2H",
        "MODIS/061/MOD13Q1",
        "JAXA/GPM_L3/GSMaP/v6/operational",
        "ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY",
        "MODIS/061/MOD09A1",
        "ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/DAILY_AGGR",
        "MODIS/061/MOD09Q1",
    ]

def get_last_date(collection): 
    ic = ee.ImageCollection(collection)
    return ic.geetools.getSTAC()["extent"]["temporal"]["interval"][0][1]

date_dict = {c: get_last_date(c) for c in list_collection}
```

---

For interested readers and as I coded the getSTAC method just for this question here is the code source. It reads the open catalog of GEE and try to find the required dataset:

```py
def getSTAC(ic: ee.ImageCollection) -> dict:
    """Gets the STAC of the image.""" 

    # extract the Asset id from the imagecollection
    assetId = ic.get("system:id").getInfo()

    # search for the project in the GEE catalog and extract the project catalog URL
    project = assetId.split("/")[0]
    catalog = "https://earthengine-stac.storage.googleapis.com/catalog/catalog.json"
    links = requests.get(catalog).json()["links"]
    project_catalog = next((i["href"] for i in links if i.get("title") == project), None)
    if project_catalog is None:
        raise ValueError(f"Project {project} not found in the catalog")

    # search for the collection in the project catalog and extract the collection STAC URL
    collection = "_".join(assetId.split("/"))
    links = requests.get(project_catalog).json()["links"]
    collection_stac = next((i["href"] for i in links if i.get("title") == collection), None)
    if collection_stac is None:
        raise ValueError(f"Collection {collection} not found in the {project} catalog")

    return requests.get(collection_stac).json()
```